# remove validation from email parameter in laravel 5.6. I am using authenticate() method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-authentication

I am trying to authenticate the using using ajax and laravel 5.6 authenticate() method. If I pass **'email'** and **'password'** parameters then it works fine but If I change the **email** parameter to **user_email** then it gives me validation that "**Email field is required**".
So I need help to authenticate the user using different parameters *(like user_email etc.)* instead of email and password.

**Here is the code file path app\Http\Controllers\AUth\LoginController.php**

```
protected function authenticate(Request $request, $user){
     if(!request->ajax()){
          return response()->json([
            'auth' => auth()->check(),
            'user' => $user,
            'intented' => $this->redirectPath()
          ]);
     }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Paste this on your login controller

```
public function username()
{
    return 'user_email';
}
```